# How to use ActiveRecord to do partial matches with joined tables?

Tags: ruby, join, activerecord, where-clause, partial

In ActiveRecord, I can do partial matches by using little tidbits of SQL like so:

```
Foo.where("name LIKE ?", "%matchthis%")
```

However, I'm looking to do something a little more complicated: use string concatenation between two tables and do a partial matches on the results.  In PostgreSQL, I'd do it like this:

```
select
  foos.id

from
  foos

join
  bars on
  bars.id = foos.bar_id

where
  foos.name || '.' || bars.name like '%match.this%'

;
```

How can I do the above using ActiveRecord?  I would greatly prefer to use only ActiveRecord syntax only, and if I can't, it would be very beneficial to have the SQL blurbs SQL-agnostic.

Comment: Please don't use fake table names. It can lead to a hard time in the translations between fake + your real data.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more ActiveRecord:

```
Foo.joins(:bars).where("foos.name || '.' || bars.name LIKE ?", '%match.this%')
```

This produces a query in AR but not sure if it is exactly what you are looking for. The query produced is:

```
SELECT "foos".* FROM "foos" 
INNER JOIN "bars" ON "bars"."foo_id" = "foos"."id" 
WHERE (foos.name || '.' || bars.name LIKE '%match.this%')
```

You might want to approach it separately like:

```
Foo.where('foos.name LIKE ?', '%match%').joins(:bars).where('bars.name LIKE ?', '%this%')


SELECT "foos".* FROM "foos" 
INNER JOIN "bars" ON "bars"."foos_id" = "foos"."id" 
WHERE (foos.name LIKE '%match%') AND (bars.name LIKE '%this%')
```

Comment: This is very close.  `||` isn't SQL agnostic, however (it will fail when using MySQL or MS-SQL, as examples).  I saw [this](https://gist.github.com/eric1234/5622690), but this still has code smell written all over it.

Comment: True but he's asking for Postgres and I happen to be using that too.

Comment: See my update. It's hard to help without a more concrete example.

Comment: And if you just want `ids` then put `.pluck(:id)` at the end.

Comment: That's a very interesting thought.  It wouldn't match `matcht` and `his`, but my use case might make this acceptable.

Comment: Like I said, hypotheticals make it harder. If you included a row or two from each that you are trying to target and the actual value of `%match.this%` it would help. If you are always looking for everything before the dot in one and everything after the dot in the other it should work.

Comment: As for matches, I provided the simplest example. I would use regex plus what I've shown above.

Comment: Your current code would not match `matcht` or `his` because you are separating them by the dot. though it should match `xxmatch` and `thisxx`.